# how to remove a specific character from a text file

Tags: python-3.x

here is my text file:

```
airport, 2007, 175702
airport, 2008, 173294
request, 2005, 646179
request, 2006, 677820
request, 2007, 697645
request, 2008, 795265
wandered, 2005, 83769
wandered, 2006, 87688
wandered, 2007, 108634
wandered, 2008, 171015
```

when I read this file using my code:

```
def readWordFile(fileName):

    for line in fileName:
        newline = line.split()
        print(newline)

def main():
    fileName = input('Enter filename: ')
    readWordFile(open(fileName))

main()
```

this is my result:

```
['airport,', '2007,', '175702']
['airport,', '2008,', '173294']
['request,', '2005,', '646179']
['request,', '2006,', '677820']
['request,', '2007,', '697645']
['request,', '2008,', '795265']
['wandered,', '2005,', '83769']
['wandered,', '2006,', '87688']
['wandered,', '2007,', '108634']
['wandered,', '2008,', '171015']
```

how do I remove the comma's that are after the word and the year?

Comment: Are you aware [`strip`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) can remove more than just whitespace?

Comment: "when I read this file using my code" - what is your code? Strip() doesn't create lists, so with what you've posted we have to guess what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the exact structure of the file, you can obtain the lists you want by doing:

```
>>> 'airport, 2007, 175702'.split(', ')
['airport', '2007', '175702']
```

However, if you're not sure whether or not there'll be spaces after a comma, you can do:

```
>>> [item.strip() for item in 'airport, 2007, 175702'.split(',')]
['airport', '2007', '175702']
```

So let's use the second approach:

```
for line in myfile:
    print([item.strip() for item in line.split(',')])
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file is comma separated values, then maybe the right approach is to use the [CSV reader module](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html) to read the content, and that will process the commas as part of it.

e.g.

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
...     for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
...         print(row)
```